# trying the perfect square can you give some tip

Tags: c++, string, loops, for-loop, nested

using only iostream why the first # is on (0) and second # is (19) and so on why ?

```
int main (){
const int walla=20; //declaring//
const int wallb=20;
const int coordinatx=walla/2;   
const int coordinaty=wallb/2;   
for(int i=0; i<walla; i++){
    cout<<"#";   //walla//
}
cout<<endl; 

    for(int i=0; i<wallb; i++){
        for (int j=0;j< walla; j++)
        if(j==0 )
            cout<<"#\n";   //trying wallb//
        else if(j==19)
            cout<<string(j,'\0');
            cout<<"#\n";
    }
}
```

//coding coordinat that prints input ty for checking (://

Comment: `cout<<"#\n";` is outside else statement. Try to add braces.

Comment: @TruthSeeker nope it didnt work

Comment: Get yourself an editor that can indent code. And don't try to save time by not typing those curly brackets.

Comment: @Fate8086: You have several errors/issues.

Comment: It isn't clear what you are trying to achieve or what the problem is. Please try to give more details on what the expect output should be and what the actual output is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Printing `\n` change line and `'\0'` is not printable.

You probably want:

```
std::cout << std::string(walla, '#') << std::endl;
for (int i = 0; i < wallb - 2; i++) {
    std::cout << '#' << std::string(walla - 2, ' ') << '#' << std::endl;
}
std::cout << std::string(walla, '#') << std::endl;
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/D6BDvw)

Comment: sir that ' ' says empty character

Comment: `' '` is a space character.

Comment: and why wallb-2 wallb is const 20 ?

Comment: As you have first line and last line `######`.

Comment: when  ' ' work and when not work and say empty character